# Why is the result of my Firestore Query inconsistent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When I query a firestore collection using "array-contains" once, it always is correct. Strangely, when I cause the function to be triggered more than once in a 20 second period, it starts returning empty results for the query that is still very much not empty. The function is triggered by a write to a completely different collection.

```
const eventDocs = await firestore()
    .collection("eventCollection")
    .where("guests", "array-contains", incorrect_uuid)
    .get()
    .catch((e) => functions.logger.info(e));
```

**Run Once (triggered by write to users collection):**

Returns firestore.QuerySnapshot<firestore.DocumentData> of size 3

**Run Twice (triggered by write to users collection, wait up to 15 seconds, write again):**

*Note that it is a different query (incorrect_uuid changes) but both should be non-empty*

Returns firestore.QuerySnapshot<firestore.DocumentData> of size 3 for the first (correct)

Returns firestore.QuerySnapshot<firestore.DocumentData> of size 0 for the second (wrong)

Comment: Can you refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#array_membership) and meanwhile `Note that it is a different query (incorrect_uuid changes)` what does it mean, do you have another query for that. If so, add that in the question.